# Airflow connection password decryption

Tags: airflow

I want to decrypt the passwords(getting the value from connection table) for airflow connections. Is there any way I can decrypt the password value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
connection = BaseHook.get_connection("conn_name")
conn_password = connection.password
conn_login = connection.login
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered a similar issue. You can now export connections in json or yaml format in Airflow 2.3.2. This will provide all the key values that an Airflow connection is represented by.

Command to run:

```
airflow connections export connections.yml --file-format yaml
```

See the Airflow documentation for more details:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/howto/connection.html#exporting-connections-from-the-cli

Answer (score 0):

1. Export your connections

`airflow connections export connections.json`

2. Install ejson to encrypt your file

`brew tap shopify/shopify && brew install ejson` or download the .deb package from [Github Releases](https://github.com/Shopify/ejson/releases).

3. Add the public key at the top of your file, as shown in the image

`ejson keygen -w`

4. Encrypt your connections

`ejson encrypt connections.json`

5. Version, the file in Git, decrypt the connections, and import them into the DB within your CI/CD pipeline

credits to [Marc Lamberti](https://www.linkedin.com/in/marclamberti/) from Astronomer

[image]