# Airflow Connection build credentials

Tags: google-analytics, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-iam

I have written a python script that works fine from the command line (with 'my-analytics.json' file stored in the same folder as the script. Now I am moving this script to AirFlow(cloud composer) where I'll be moving this code to PythonOperator.

Note(context) : This script sends an API request to delete a user from Google Analytics.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'my-analytics.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
  scopes=SCOPES
)
analytics_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
  'analytics',
  'v3',
  credentials=credentials
)

user_deletion_request_resource = analytics_client.userDeletion().userDeletionRequest()

def delete_users(id):
    return user_deletion_request_resource.upsert(
    body = {
    "deletionRequestTime": str(datetime.datetime.now()),
    "kind": "analytics#userDeletionRequest",  
    "id": {  
        "userId": id,  
        "type": "CLIENT_ID",  # Type of user (APP_INSTANCE_ID,CLIENT_ID or USER_ID)
    },
    "webPropertyId": "UA-XXXXX-YY"  # Web property ID of the form UA-XXXXX-YY.
    }
    ).execute()
```

I have created a Google Analytics connection like this and stored json into KeyFile JSON field.
[image]

My question is how do I build "credentials" from this connection? I do not know how to replace `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'my-analytics.json'` with AirFlow connection. Any help/guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Airflow it's better to code with hooks and operators this way the connection will work out of the box without all the extra manual work.

In any case as for your question. It's similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166549/14624409)
The difference is that Google connection has unique fields so you will need to use GoogleBaseHook.

```
from airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google import GoogleBaseHook
gcp_hook = GoogleCloudBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="your_conn")
scope = gcp_hook._get_field('scope') # or gcp_hook.scope
keyfile = gcp_hook._get_field('keyfile_dict')
keyfile_path = gcp_hook._get_field('key_path')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. I'll try to use hooks & will come back if have any further question.